# Submit a new script after all parallel jobs in R have completed

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have an R script that creates multiple scripts and submits these simultaneously to a computer cluster, and after all of the multiple scripts have completed and the output has been written in the respective folders, I would like to automatically launch another R script that works on these outputs.

I haven't been able to figure out whether there is a way to do this in R: the function 'wait' is not what I want since the scripts are submitted as different jobs and each of them completes and writes its output file at different times, but I actually want to run the subsequent script after all of the outputs appear.

One way I thought of is to count the files that have been created and, if the correct number of output files are there, then submit the next script. However to do this I guess I would have to have a script opened that checks for the presence of the files every now and then, and I am not sure if this is a good idea since it probably takes a day or more before the completion of the first scripts.

Can you please help me find a solution?

Thank you very much for your help
-fra

Comment: what OS are you on? In Unix, I know there are other scheduling tasks that may be a better fit for this sort of thing...?

Comment: Hi Chase, Yes OS is Linux, what sort of scheduling task?

Comment: i'll let Dirk take over...he's much better at these things than I am and mentioned most of the things I had in mind (and others)...good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at this the wrong way:

- Not an R problem at all, R happens to be the client of your batch job.
- This is an issue that queue / batch processors can address on your cluster.
- Worst case you could just wait/sleep in a shell (or R script) til a 'final condition reached' file has been touched
- Inter-dependencies can be expressed with make too

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you. There seems to be no function to do this within the cluster, maybe as you say it would be good to do the wait/sleep script, but how do I set up the 'final condition reached' file? Is it by checking if all the output files are present?

Comment: First line of script: `[ test -f done.txt && rm done.txt`. Last line: `touch done.txt`.  Then the other script does `while [ ! -f done.txt]; do sleep 5; done` or something.  But this super-hackish.  Do talk to local experts: if there is a cluster, there usually are solutions to do this better: slurm, torque, pbs, condor, ...

Comment: Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow. It is comming to "upvote" (click on triangle pointing up) and/or "accept" (click on tickmark; only you as the person asking the question sees that) answers you consider helpful.